# How to delete from a combobox

Tags: user-interface, combobox

Say you had a combobox like this one:

[image]

How would one allow the user to delete an entry listed in the combobox? What element would you add, such as an additional button, context menu ...?

Comment: Nice question but i think it belongs more to http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think small 'x' mark at the right side would be sufficient here.

However I think better solution is to use something like select2: https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

[image: Select2 tagging solution].

I believe users are more familiar with this kind of input.